# Starting activity from phonegap plugin-webIntent

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have configured webintent plugin in my android app . I want to start an activity from a button click on my UI page . The activity takes no params . I have gone through this link 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/WebIntent/ but i m not getting how to call a such a simple activity . Not able to get the what url field is used for .... . One more , are thing any configuration required in manifest file such as intent filters for calling activity .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if that could help :

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/issues/1009

https://github.com/Richardsonke/phonegap-plugins/commit/d0343f49022d9ece97f70af42400636d8d0a64d8

**EDIT 1:**
Ok I got it working now,
in your AndroidManifest.xml add these Lines ( Inside the Activity you want the Button to go to )

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.example.yourapplication.UNIQUESTRING" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

be sure to change "com.example.yourapplication" to your package
and UNIQUESTRING to be something Unique

in Javascript make the button fires this JS :

```
window.plugins.webintent.startActivity(
  {
    action: 'com.example.yourapplication.UNIQUESTRING',
  }, 
  function() {}, 
  function() {alert('Failed to open URL via Android Intent')}
);
```

Comment: Thanks man...i too figured the same way..forgot to mention here....just hoping that this is correct way of doing this..