# enable GPS using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm new with phonegap and I want to switch user to location settings in android  to enable GPS if it is disabled, Is there a way to do that or a way to enable GPS directly ??
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some details.

Comment: i'm building a program that uses maps, so i want at the start of the program to check the GPS if enabled, ok but if not I want to show alert that GPS is disabled and switch user to location settings to enable GPS... using phonegap for android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally i found the answer:
first:used gps detector plugin to check gps statues
then:used webintent plugin to open location settings
useful links:
use plugin:
[Starting activity from phonegap plugin-webIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336248/starting-activity-from-phonegap-plugin-webintent)

how to write java code to start location settings:
[How to redirect towards GPS setting window in android or ios using phonegap for on or off a GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620140/how-to-redirect-towards-gps-setting-window-in-android-or-ios-using-phonegap-for)